# Issue with importing aws_iam_role_policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, import, terraform, terragrunt

I have used terragrunt to manage my infrastructure. I am trying to import the inline policy attached with IAM role but its keep giving me the error below

**Import command used:**

```
terragrunt import aws_iam_role_policy.aws_load_balancer_controller cp-sw-ore-nonprod-aws-load-balancer-controller:cp-sw-ore-nonprod-alb-management
```

**Reference Terraform Link:**
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy

```
WARN[0039] No double-slash (//) found in source URL /koralkloud/tg-module-eks.git. Relative paths in downloaded Terraform code may not work. 
aws_iam_role_policy.aws_load_balancer_controller: Importing from ID "cp-sw-ore-nonprod-aws-load-balancer-controller:cp-sw-ore-nonprod-alb-management"...
aws_iam_role_policy.aws_load_balancer_controller: Import prepared!
  Prepared aws_iam_role_policy for import
aws_iam_role_policy.aws_load_balancer_controller: Refreshing state... [id=cp-sw-ore-nonprod-aws-load-balancer-controller:cp-sw-ore-nonprod-alb-management]

Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object

While attempting to import an existing object to
aws_iam_role_policy.aws_load_balancer_controller, the provider detected that
no object exists with the given id. Only pre-existing objects can be imported;
check that the id is correct and that it is associated with the provider's
configured region or endpoint, or use "terraform apply" to create a new remote
object for this resource.

Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
ERRO[0047] 1 error occurred:
    * exit status 1
```

**Additional information :**

I am using

```
terraform version : 0.14.5    
provider version : 4.29
```

**Note** : we explicitly need the above mentioned version.

It would be great if you could help me to resolve the issue.

**Similar issues:**
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10145

Comment: Your link is to `aws_iam_policy`, not to `aws_iam_role_policy`. So what exactly do you try to import?

Comment: If you're sure that the role policy exists, then I would assume that the bug report you've linked to is what you're encountering.

Comment: Can you add the code you are actually using for the import?